# Checking for empty cells with OpenPyXl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlsx, openpyxl

I've poured over numerous versions of this same question, but simply cannot find a working solution for looping through a group of cells and checking for empty ones.

Here's my code:

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook(write_only=False)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
for i in range(1, 20):
    if sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value == None or 'None':
        print('Space' + str(i))
        sheet.cell(row=i, column=1) = i
    else:
        pass

wb.save('filename.xlsx')
```

But for some reason it writes to the empty cells AND overwrites the cells which had values written in them.

I comment out the loop I find that if I run the code it erases everything that was manually written into the spreadsheet to begin with. Maybe that's part of the problem?

Also I'm using LibreOffice if that makes a difference

Comment: The second part of your if statement will always evaluate to `True` which is why you overwrite existing cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Charlie mentions is of course correct.

Non empty strings in Python evaluate to `True`, so you are actually testing if cell value is None or if `bool('None')`, and the later is always `True`, hence your condition always evaluates to `True`.

To address your specific case I'm not sure why you are trying to test for an empty cell with `'None'`.

In case you really want to do this your condition should look like this:

```
if sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value in [None,'None']
```

If you want test for None or an empty string, so `None or ''` then of course your condition should be:

```
if sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value in [None,'']
```

Hope this gets you on the right track..