# When you delete rows in Openpyxl, the max_row doesn't seem to change; What do you do to fix that?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a script that's deleting rows from an existing xlsx spreadsheet, and after deleting it desn't seem to update the `max_row` variable of the sheet.  I've also tried closing the sheet and reloading it, but the variable does not update.

Can I set the max_row variable manually every time I delete a row?

I'm using Openpyxl 2.5.x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openpyxl max\_row and max\_column wrongly reports a larger figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569496/openpyxl-max-row-and-max-column-wrongly-reports-a-larger-figure)

Comment: check for non-empty cells but they are extremely dependent upon the implementation.

Comment: @min2bro How do you mean?