# How do I find the max row in Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

The max_row function returns a value higher than it should be (the largest row that has a value in it is row 7, but max_row returns 10), and if I try iterating through a column to find the first row that has nothing in it I get the same value as max_row.

Comment: did you try printing the data?

Comment: yes, when I print the cell's value I get "None"

Comment: is ```max_row``` matching with ```len(ws.rows)```?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569496/openpyxl-max-row-and-max-column-wrongly-reports-a-larger-figure) will help you out?

Comment: len(ws.rows) just returns an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openpyxl max\_row and max\_column wrongly reports a larger figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569496/openpyxl-max-row-and-max-column-wrongly-reports-a-larger-figure)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the excel file and also some example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to understand if you work with excel on java.
Excel cell have properties which define them as active or inactive. If you enter a value to a cell then delete the value, the cell still remains active.
max_row returns the row number of the last active cell, hence you get 10 rather than 7 even if the sheet now have data only till row 7 it may once have data till 10.

Manually you can clear the cell (Editing->Clear->Clear All) for the cell in excel making it inactive again. Not sure how to do the same via code in python.