# Openpyxl 3 counts the empty row after saving custom cell format in MsExcel

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Openpyxl 3.0.3,

Python 3.8.3,

MSExcel 16.27 (2019)

Reproduction:
In MSExcel, create workbook. Fill and save it similar to this,

[image]

Run the following code,

```
filepath = '..../yoursfilepath/Test.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook (filepath)
ws = wb.active
print (ws.max_row)
```

Note down the `max_row` count.

Now open the workbook in MSExcel and clear all the content in last row (here, 12-May-20) which have cell format as 'Custom' (any other than 'General')
[image]

Save it and run the above code again. It counts last row.
Even if you convert the Custom format to General, it counts that row with empty cells.

If you check cell values with `ws.iter_rows ()` they are 'None' for that row.

However, if you delete that particular row using MSExcel and save it, we get correct max row count. But this cannot be the solution all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html) states not to create the Worksheet yourself, I presume that this is a known bug when manually creating worksheets.

> Do not create worksheets yourself, use openpyxl.workbook.Workbook.create_sheet() instead

However, if you must manually create them, this may solve your issue (modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46571480/11916773))

```
def getMaxRows(ws):
    rows = 0
    for max_row, row in enumerate(ws, 1):
        if all(c.value is None for c in row):
            break
        rows += 1
    return rows
```

Comment: Yup... I also did with None check, but sometimes it gets edited and saved in MSExcel unintentionally. Then we need to recreate the sheet with openpyxl. In such cases all the previous data collection is required to do even for a small change.